# Finding what images are missing from a PDF

Tags: python, image, pdf, count, detection

I have a PDF file that is generated by an external software over which I have no control (I want this to be clear from the start).

This PDF file is basically a bunch of labels, there are 8 rows and 2 columns of labels (that is 14 labels in total).

Each label carries the information of a product. Some of that info is in image form. Each label has to have 2 images (one corresponds to the photo of the product, and the other image is a barcode converted to an image by the software that outputs the file in the first place).

I've been able to come up with python scripts that count the number of images on the page, but it's never the actual number of images displayed, it's only the images present inside the file.

Since the images have to appear in pairs on each label, my idea is to detect the ones that are alone, and give me the page where there are missing images. This way I can go back and fix this in the other program.

I initially (an foolishly) though that detecting an odd number of images on a page would give me the answer. It does work, until you are missing an even number of images, then it doesn't give you a correct answer.

Does anyone have an idea of how to pull this off?

```
import pdfplumber

pdf_file = 'file.pdf'

with pdfplumber.open(pdf_file) as pdf:
    for i, page in enumerate(pdf.pages):
        image_count = 0
        for image in page.images:
            if image['width'] > 0 and image['height'] > 0:
                image_count += 1
        if image_count % 2 != 0:
            print(f'Page {i+1} has an odd number of images.')
```

[image: Here is what the PDF looks like, this may help people understand what I'm trying to achieve.]

Comment: You can use [pymupdf](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/) to find the images and their positions (bbox = boundary box) on the page. Then check things like the image count is an even number and that bbox of image number 2n+1 is to right of the bbox of image number 2n.

Comment: Additionally, if you can get the number of labels on which you are supposed to have two images, then you can check if `label_count*2 == image_count`.

Comment: @timthefiend do you mean like this? 

        `if image_count == 2:
            print(f'Page {i+1} has two images.')
        elif image_count % 2 != 0:
            print(f'Page {i+1} has an odd number of images.')`

Comment: @JeromeCremades Excuse me, I wrote a bad comment; I meant to ask if there's a reason you don't check the possibility of `image_count` being 0?

Comment: @KJ There are no corrupt images, just missing images.